# InkScape: how to make a straight path line to arc?

Tags: inkscape

I drew a straight line with "Bezier"-tool, and wish to make it arc, just like a slice of a circle:

[image]

Note: red is the circle's arc, and I wish to make the straight line the same. (Line is not straight anymore, as I already tried to make it 'arc').

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with a sharp corner, switch to node-editing mode and click on the new 'Add Corners LPE' button (added in Inkscape version 1.3, but also available in previous versions in the 'Path → Path Effects...' panel):

[image: Screenshot of node-tool toolbar with 'Add Corners LPE' button highlighted]

This will add new handles at corner-nodes that you can drag to set a radius:

[image: Sequence of screenshots showing dragging corner handles step-by-step]

Alternatively, <kbd>shift</kbd>-click the handle to set specific values and other parameters:

[image: Dialog for setting corner parameters]

This will add actual arc-commands to the path-data (e.g. `a 50,50 0 0 1 50,50`), so it produces actual circle segments, not just bezier-curve appoximations.

Comment: Perfect. Should be noted this is also available on version 1.2 as *Path Effects/Corners*.

Comment: @Daniel Good point! I edited my post.

Answer (score 1):

You can't turn a single straight line into an actual arc. Arcs are a function of the ellipse tool.

There are alternatives however. Here are a few:

- Bend a straight line by clicking and dragging on it with the
  nodes tool
- Adjust the Bézier handles manually to get them to match an
  arc.
- Use the Spiro path option in the controls bar for the Pen tool to create nice curves by simply clicking where you want to add nodes around a curve
- Add a Spiro path effect (in the Path Effects panel) to an existing line, and add a smooth node in the middle, and move it to create a curve that's close to an arc

This is an example of using the Spiro Path option for the Pen Tool. It's probably the easiest solution if you don't want to mess around too much with Bézier handles, etc.

[image]